# How to use the standard eclipse font (java) in spyder (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, spyder, appearance

I only can see a limited amount of fonts, but i know it was possible to use at least a similar font. However i forgot how to make that happen. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the preference tab highlighted you can :

1.Change keyboard shortcut as in eclipse

2.In syntax coloring :choose "spyder"

In view--> windows layout --> spyder default

In view -->Panes , you can add file explorer,variable explorer and all tabs that were in your eclipse.